# How to run a gulp task from Node.js - Any better alternative to gulp.start()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I would like to know what is the proper way to run a gulp task from a node application.

At the moment I am using the following code, but I would like to know if:

- How to detect when the task has been executed with success?
- Detect any errors within the task?

I read that `gulp.start()` it was not really intended as a public API, if it is true, what are the options?

```
require('./gulpfile.js');
gulp.start('release', function () {
  // do smt
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that `gulp.start()` is not not part of the [Offical Gulp API](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/b2915d7fa094475e42bf0400dacd0070029051c8/docs/API.md). That's because gulp tasks aren't really supposed to be executed from other applications but rather the command line.

However Gulp itself inherits most of its task running abilities, including the `start()` function, from another project called [Orchestrator](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator)

(And when I say it 'inherits' them, I *literally*  mean ['inherits'](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/b2915d7fa094475e42bf0400dacd0070029051c8/index.js#L12). Gulp is really not much more than Orchestrator + [Node.js Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) + [Vinyl files](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs) + some glue + [lots and lots of plugins](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/).)

Now Orchestrator itself is *very much* supposed to be executed from within a regular Node.js application. That means there's really no good technical reason not to use the `gulp.start()` function.

Since `gulp.start()` is just inherited from `orchestrator.start()` all the [accompaning documentation](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratorstarttasks-cb) applies. That documentation has the answer to your question about detecting successful termination and errors during task execution:

```
gulp.start('release', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    // an error occured
  } else {
    // success
  }
});
```

**One caveat however:** since `gulp.start()` is not part of the offical API it is subject to change. That change is already on the horizon. Starting with version 4.0 Gulp will no longer inherit from Orchestrator, but from  [Undertaker](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker). That means `gulp.start()` will be gone and replaced by `gulp.series()` and `gulp.parallel()`:

```
gulp.series('release')(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // an error occured
  } else {
    // success
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp automatically looks for your default task in your gulpfile and runs it if it's there; you don't have to use gulp.start().

```
gulp.task('default', ['dependencyTask1name', ..., 'dependencyTaskXname'], function () {
  // Do stuff, produce output, what-have-you. I usually just place a console.log statement here with distinctive output, as well as inside every other task.
});
```

Gulp notifies you in terminal on the start and end of every task.

```
[01:27:54] Starting 'default'...
[01:27:54] Finished 'default' after 51 μs
```

If Gulp is unable to complete a task due to an error, it will output that error to terminal as well. Example task:

```
gulp.task('routerStuff', function() {
  console.log('routes compiling.');
  return gulp.src('./source/index.js')
      .pipe(babel())s
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./routes/'));
});
```

Output in terminal:

```
$ gulp
/Users/EMC3/Documents/node-wordpress/gulpfile.js:35
      .pipe(babel())s
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
...
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I need to detect errors and open a specific task directly from node JS application and not from command line.